# Is it possible to show the `WORKDIR` when building a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have a problem with the `WORKDIR` when we building a docker image. Is it possible to print the value of `WORKDIR`?

We tried:

```
ECHO ${WORKDIR}
```

But there is no such instruction `ECHO`

Answer (score 72):

There's no builtin way for Docker to print the `WORKDIR` during a build. You can inspect the final workdir for an image/layer via the `.Config.WorkingDir` property in the `inspect` output:

```
docker image inspect -f '{{.Config.WorkingDir}}' {image-name}
```

It's possible to view a Linux containers build steps workdir by printing the shells default working directory:

```
RUN pwd
```

or the shell often stores the working directory in the PWD environment variable

```
RUN echo "$PWD"
```

If the `RUN` step has run before and is cached, add the `--no-cache` flag.
If you are using newer versions of docker with *BuildKit*, stdout from the build will need to be enabled with `--progress=plain`

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain .
```

Comment: tried `RUN pwd` and `CMD pwd`, it does not print anything in the console while building the image. It only prints to the container's console.

Comment: Are you using something other than docker to build the image? or maybe using `-q` or getting a cached build in docker?

Comment: I use `docker build`, and also tried `--no-cache` flag

Comment: @Matt I think it does not work with BuildKit (only executed command is printend, not the output).

Comment: @Wirone Thanks. can you confirm the fix? My docker instances are apparently stuck in the dark ages

Comment: I think the most foolproof is probably `RUN echo $(pwd)`

Comment: @troyfolger How would that change the output from a plain `pwd`?

Comment: @matt `RUN pwd` executes the `pwd` command ... the output is by default captured by the docker building process. `RUN echo $(pwd)` is telling RUN to *show* the output of the command. Try it both ways and see for yourself.

Comment: @troyfolger buildkit doesn't differentiate between the stdout of `pwd` or the stdout of `echo`. both are commands passed to sh.

Answer (score 17):

There seems some recent change to the `docker build` command, where it hides `stdout` during the build process.

In short use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build` to get the "old" behavior back.

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805337/16174836))

Answer (score 12):

You can use below command in Dockerfile

```
RUN pwd && ls
```

Run the build with --progress=plain

```
docker build -t <image-name-you-want-to-give> --progress=plain .
```

Answer (score 11):

You can check the content of directories during build steps and print it with commands like

```
RUN ls
RUN ls ..
```

Under ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS WSL2 I have to combine `--progress=plain` with debug mode and no-cache to see output:

```
docker -D build --progress=plain --no-cache.
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. It simply just shows the sha of the command and not the actual echo output.

Answer (score 2):

RUN doesn't print in my IDE console if I use `docker-compose up`.
But CMD does. So try

`CMD pwd`

In case you have python in the image, this should also work

`CMD ["python", "-c", "import os;print(os.getcwd())"]`

Please note, **only** one, **the last CMD command will be executed** in the "container-run" phase. All others will be silently ignored. On the other side, there is a standard piping workaround:

`CMD pwd && ls`

Answer (score 2):

I add the line to my dockerfile:

`RUN pwd`

To print the current workdir and then build the image using the command:

```
docker compose build --no-cache <name of service> 2>&1 | tee build.log
```

This will print the output in the terminal in a more verbose format and also do a complete log to the file build.log

I would expect you to be able to do something similar using just a docker command if you do not use docker compose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below command

```
RUN `echo ls`
```