# Why is docker build not showing any output from commands?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Snippet from my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.18.0
RUN echo "hello world"
RUN psql --version
```

When I run `docker build .` I don't see any output from these two commands even if they are not cached. The documentation says that `docker build` is verbose by default. Why am I not seeing the output from commands? I used to see them before.

The output while building:

```
=> [7/18] RUN echo "hello world"                         0.9s
```

The output I am seeing after building finishes:

```
=> CACHED [6/18] RUN apt-get install postgresql -y      0.0s
=> [7/18] RUN echo "hello world"                        6.4s
=> [8/18] RUN psql --version                           17.1s
```

The `Dockerfile` is created from node:12.18.0 which is based on Debian 9.

Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d.

Answer (score 670, accepted):

The output you are showing is from buildkit, which is a replacement for the classic build engine that docker ships with. You can adjust output from this with the `--progress` option:

```
  --progress string         Set type of progress output (auto, plain, tty). Use plain to show container output
                            (default "auto")
```

Adding `--progress=plain` will show the output of the run commands that were not loaded from the cache. This can also be done by setting the `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` variable:

```bash
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

---

If you are debugging a build, and the steps have already been cached, add `--no-cache` to your build to rerun the steps and redisplay the output:

```
docker build --progress=plain --no-cache ...
```

---

If you don't want to use buildkit, you can revert to the older build engine by exporting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` in your shell, e.g.:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...
```

or

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
docker build ...
```

Comment: The answer regarding `--progress=plain` does not appear to work anymore. On OS X for me, it merely spits out the command, hash, and step result (e.g. "CACHED"). Only forcibly disabling buildkit returns any useful output now. Is this a recent change, or different depending on platform?

Comment: @Jon if the step is cached, no command is run, so there's no output to show. It's the same with or without buildkit.

Comment: use `docker build --progress=plain --no-cache ...` to disable caching and print all output

Comment: I would not recommend disabling build kit.

Comment: @ruohola neither would I. That's why I push for `--progress=plain`. But some people just want things the old way no matter what advice you give.

Comment: I'd like to know who in their right mind at Docker decided to hide the caching hashes by default. "Hey we're going to break every Docker debug tutorial on the planet, lets go for it!". They gave a big ol' middle finger to the dev community IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Have to side with @JustinFortier. I am currently trying to examine the contents of an image that fails to build completely, but neither `plain`, nor `tty` gives me any usable output, which is not great.

Comment: `--no-cache` appears to have no effect.  All the commands are still `CACHED`.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, please post a new question with a [mcve] or a separate answer with what does work if it's different from the answers here.

Comment: I used this command and logged it to file and observed that the entire output is logged to stderr (for whatever reason). So use `docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache --progress=plain . |& tee build_output.txt` if you are vintage and want to have the output in a file or if you do not have access to stdout.

Answer (score 152):

Just use this flag `--progress=plain` after `build`.

For example:

```
docker compose build --progress=plain <container_name>
```

OR

```
docker build --progress=plain .
```

If you don't want to use this flag every time, then permanently tell  docker to use this flag by doing:

```
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

Here is the official documentation when you type `docker build --help`.

```
--progress string         Set type of progress output (auto, plain, tty). Use plain to show container output (default "auto")
```

Comment: You might need to clear your docker build cache to see output instead of the hash from the previous build. A brute force way to do that is `docker system prune`

Comment: Does not work with docker-compose, `unknown flag: --progress`

Comment: It works for me, which version of docker-compose are you on ? `docker-compose -v` @PeterKionga-Kamau

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau Have you ensured to use `--progress` after `docker-compose build` not before, as mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: @AshSingh yes of course.
`docker-compose -p output-test -f docker-compose.custom.yml --verbose up -d --build --progress=plain`

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau You are using `docker-compose up` command not `docker-compose build`. This question is about docker build not about running the container.

Comment: @AshSingh aha! ty ty. very true. This explains some of the issues we've been having with options order too.

Comment: How to set `export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain` on Windows? I am using PowerShell.

Answer (score 44):

In Docker 20.10 i had to use the --no-cache flag, too. Otherwise cached output is not shown.

```
docker build --progress=plain --no-cache .
```

Comment: `--no-cache` doesn't just hide the cached output, it disables Docker's layer caching completely. You certainly don't want to use that all the time.

Comment: Yes, one thing has nothing to do with the other. Docker by default caches build steps. When you change a line and build again, every subsequent line will be built again by default, because there's no need to repeat existing steps, they're already cached.

Comment: I used `--no-cache` but I still see `CACHED` on the commands :/

Answer (score 35):

#### Do 2 things

1. Instead of `docker build .` use this

```
docker build . --progress=plain
```

2. Add random junk to your `RUN` command every build (this tricks docker into thinking it hasn't seen the command before, so it doesn't use the cached version)

**Example**. If your command is `RUN ls` use this instead `RUN ls && echo sdfjskdflsjdf` (change the `sdfjskdflsjdf` to something else each time you build).

#### Why this works

I tried other answers and they all presented problems and imperfections. It's highly frustrating that Docker doesn't have some simple functionality like `--verbose=true`.

Here's what I ended up using (it's ludicrous but it works).

Suppose you want to see the output of `ls` command, this **won't** work `docker build .`

```
RUN ls
```

but this *will* print the output `docker build --progress=plain`:

```
RUN ls
```

now try again, it **won't** print! - that's because docker caches the unchanged layer, so the trick is to alter the command each time by adding some nonsense to it `&& echo sdfljsdfljksdfljk`, and changing the nonsense each time `docker build --progress=plain`:

```
# This prints
RUN ls && echo sdfljsdfljksdfljk
```

```
# Next time you run it use a different token
RUN ls && echo sdlfkjsldfkjlskj
```

So each and every time, I mash the keyboard and come up with a new token. Stupifying. (note that I tried something like `&& openssl rand -base64 12` to generate a random string, but docker realises the code hasn't changed that doesn't work).

This solution is highly inferior to genuine docker support for printing output to console.

Comment: Just no. Use `ARG` Dockerfile statements and then in your `RUN` statement, do `&& echo $ARG_NAME`. At build time, do `--build-arg ARG_NAME=$(date)`. Any command referencing an ARG that has changed will have its layer invalidated.

Comment: @ErikE that's a nice idea. I'll try it when I get a chance, update the answer to reflect it, and credit you

Comment: Just be aware that if you use build stages, you must have an `ARG` before the first `FROM` and then another `ARG` inside each `FROM` stage that you want to use the `ARG` in. You can make `ARG` values non-required by setting a default value, allowing you to cache-bust any time you want, or not. Oh, and you don't even need to put the arg usage in a layer. Just put it in the statement before, such as `ENV SOMETHING=$ARG_NAME` which will invalidate all subsequent layers.

Comment: Cool. I haven't used `ARG` before so I don't understand just from hearing the suggestion, but I'm sure it will make sense to me when I try it. Thanks again

Comment: `ARG LS_VERSION=none; FROM imagename AS install; ARG LS_VERSION; RUN echo $LS_VERSION; RUN ls` (converting semicolons to newlines). Now you can `docker build` and `LS_VERSION` will be set to `none`, or you can `docker build --build-arg LS_VERSION=1` and cache-bust (or `date` or whatever you like).

Comment: it doesn't work. nah. `#10 [builder  7/12] RUN ls -la
#10 CACHED`

Comment: @MrHIDEn note that docker is saying that layer is cached. If you did the first step (build with `docker build --progress=plain`), then you still need to add random junk to your command. So instead of `RUN ls -la` try `RUN ls -la && echo 'abcdefg'` (and alter what’s echoed each build so docker sees it as a ‘new’ layer)

Answer (score 29):

As an alternative to specifying the `--progress=plain` option, you can also permanently disable the "pretty" output by setting this env variable in your shell config:

```
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

Comment: This is gold, thanks. Very useful for devops pipelines!

Answer (score 0):

If your error looks something like this:

`#7 0.584 /bin/sh: 1: /install.sh: not found`

it's telling you the error is in line number 1. you are running into [windows line endings](https://superuser.com/questions/948862/linux-sh-script-throws-bin-sh-not-found/948866#948866)

I was using VS code and I solved it pretty easily by converting the file from CRLF to LF using VS code.

just click on the CRLF button in the bottom right corner of the editor and save the file.

everything should work fine when you build the image now.