# How do you print to console from a docker file during build?

Tags: docker

Suppose you have some Dockerfile. What needs to be added to that file such that a string (ie "Hello World") is printed to the console during build?

`docker build .`

*RESEARCH*

This question is a top hit in Google for this topic. I have researched by googling and landing here.

*WHAT I HAVE TRIED*

From the accepted answer:

```
RUN echo "hello there"
```

This actually doesn't work.

Comment: What research did you do? What have you tried? What documentation did you read?

Comment: I guess you can add `RUN echo "Hello World"` in your Dockerfile. Is this what you want ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Docker build not showing any output from commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64804749/596285)

Comment: @norbjd This does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's fairly simple actually.
If you just want to print stuff using in the build proccess you could just add the following line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "hello there"
```

And then add these options to your `docker build` command:

```
--progress=plain --no-cache
```

EDIT:

as noted by @SoftwareEngineer, when used for logging or tooling purposes you should append the echo command to the one you want to check if were successful. for example when downloading packages and wanting to get a print statement when finished:
[example from nginx official image dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/ab8516ed3a212d8a03392567c8f55c570c839e59/stable/debian/Dockerfile)

```
RUN apt-get install -y whatever && echo "installed package"
```

Comment: Though, I wouldn't recommend actually doing this

Comment: I agree it's a bit odd to say the least but other than it's not best practice, why wouldn't you recommend this @SoftwareEngineer ? for testing purposes for example

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little clearer. My objection is to running this in its own `RUN` command and creating an extra layer just to produce output. For debugging and audit purposes there is nothing intrinsically wrong with producing logging output. I just wouldn't recommend doing it in this specific way.

Comment: The --progress=plain --no-cache is key.

Comment: @DanielViglione what OS and docker installation method are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep notes to remind myself what I am doing and display logs to myself to verify that it happens in this version.
RUN it is

```
# Copy local config into container
COPY config/kibana.yml /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml

# Verify that local configuration file is copied in & enables SSL/TLS
RUN ls -l /opt/kibana/config/
```