# Why aren't all of my Docker commands executing during build?

Tags: docker, docker-build

EDIT: I figured it out: I built the container without the run command, and it seems that it had downloaded miniconda as ' Miniconda.sh' with a space -.- so all my other commands were missing. Thank you!

This is my Dockerfile.

```
#
# Building a docker image with the latest ubuntu version and basic python install
#
# latest ubuntu version
FROM ubuntu:latest

# information about maintainer
MAINTAINER yves

# add the bash script
ADD install.sh /
# change rights for the script
RUN chmod u+x /install.sh
# run the bash script
RUN /install.sh
# prepend the new path
ENV PATH /root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

# execute IPython when container is run
CMD ["ipython"]
```

When I build with

```
docker build -t pyalgo:basic .
```

However, it shows in the logs that not every command is executing.

[image]

Only four commands are executed in the log:

```
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [2/4] ADD install.sh /                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [3/4] RUN chmod u+x /install.sh                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => [4/4] RUN /install.sh
```

I have tried to find out why this is happening but I don't get it. It seems to be finding the file and everything.

EDIT: I tried using the following advice about --progress, but it still seems to only use 4 commands:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAk2z.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is docker build not showing any output from commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804749/docker-build-not-showing-any-output-from-commands)

Comment: @GinoMempin I tried showing more output, but it does not seem to be an output problem, as using --progress=plain still shows only 4 commands

Comment: Are you expecting `MAINTAINER` and the last `CMD` to be shown as well?

Answer (score 0):

Docker now uses [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements) by default to build Linux containers.

If you want to see all the build steps, you can either use `--progress` in BuildKit:

```sh
docker build --progress=plain ...
```

or, you can ask Docker to use the classic builder over BuildKit:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...
```

Comment: I suspected that it wasn't executing all the steps because things that should have been installed were not. I tried using the --progress tag, but it still seems like only 4 steps are being executed.

Comment: What is the full command you used? And did you try the second command?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I figured it out: I built the container without the run command, and it seems that it had downloaded miniconda as ' Miniconda.sh' with a space -.- so all my other commands were missing. Thank you!