# jupyter ! magic command have no output text

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, ipython

https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks

In Jupyter Notebook you can execute Terminal commands in the notebook cells by prepending an exclamation point/bang(!) to the beginning of the command.

When i run `!docker info`, there is output

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.6.0)
```

but however when i run `!docker-compose up --build`  
there is no output, why? I would like to have output to see the build log.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. Your question isn't about [tag:python] at all anyway.

Comment: Many `docker` commands don't print their output to standard output. Try adding `--progress=plain` to the options {but actually I suppose you want `--detach` and no output to leave the containers running while you do other things).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is docker build not showing any output from commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804749/why-is-docker-build-not-showing-any-output-from-commands)