# docer-compose.yml in Django project: environment variables are not created from the .env file

Tags: django, docker-compose, env-file

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: 
      - .dev.env
```

my `Dockerfile` in `./app`:

```
FROM kuralabs/python3-dev

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# RUN pip install --upgrade pip 

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

My file `.dev.env`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS='localhost 127.0.0.1'
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY='django-insecure-...'
```

[image: My catalog in attached]

I run the project with the commands:

```bash
$docker-compose build
$docker-compose up -d
```

I get variables in `settings.py`:

```py
load_dotenv()
print(f'Environment: {os.environ}')
```

my variables from the '.dev.env' file are not in the list of environment variables.

Please help me understand why `.dev.env` variables don't get into the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables from a .env file by assigning them to your service, take the following example

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  something:
    image: someimage
    container_name: comecontainer
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MARIADB_DATABASE
```

The environment variables are directly read from the `.env` file located next to the docker-compose.yaml. Note that `env_file` still works the same way. So instead of reading from the `.env` file, you can utilize `env_file` to target (in your case)
the `.dev.env` file.

Hope this helps.

---

In addition, perhaps you could assign the path of `load_dotenv`.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath

dotenv_path = PurePosixPath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent, '.dev.env').as_posix()
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
```

That should also work, when placed somewhere after your imports in `manage.py`.

Comment: version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS
      - DEBUG
      - SECRET_KEY
    env_file:
      - .dev.env

I added "environment:" in docer-compose, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: 1. Upgrade your compose version to 3.9, Make sure you execute `docker-compose up --build` in the folder location where your .env file is located. This should work as I'm doing it myself too. If this doesn't work for you, (exec into container -> echo env), 2. perhaps you could stick with the python solution instead.

Comment: I add into Dockerfile:
RUN ECHO ENV



Step 5/8 : RUN echo ENV
 ---> Running in e7db48f6e2ee
ENV



and I didnt see variables....

Comment: @EvoluSpace, This is because docker just squashes your stdout and your echo gets lost in the layering system of docker, please refer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804749/why-is-docker-build-not-showing-any-output-from-commands)