# docker buildx build: how not to omit logs?

Tags: docker, logging, devops, buildx

I use docker buildx build because currently I need to see how much time does every stage consume.

For instance, this looks good:

```
#14 [runner  4/11] RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
#14 DONE 0.4s

#15 [deps 5/8] COPY package.json .npmrc ./
#15 DONE 0.3s

#16 [deps 6/8] COPY package-lock.json .npmrc ./
#16 DONE 0.0s

#17 [deps 7/8] RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=***" >> .npmrc
#17 DONE 0.1s

#18 [runner  5/11] RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
#18 DONE 0.1s
```

But sometimes some of the stages lack the consumed time mark:

```
#8 [deps 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
#0 1.680 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 1.856 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 2.171 (1/2) Upgrading musl (1.2.3-r1 -> 1.2.3-r2)
#0 2.188 (2/2) Installing libc6-compat (1.2.3-r2)
#0 2.194 OK: 8 MiB in 17 packages
#8 ...

#10 [runner  3/11] RUN npm install -g http-server
#10 ...
```

See, these stages end with "ellipsis" ("..."). More than that, the actual logs piece is just cut off. Only some of the first lines are displayed.

**What do I do wrong?**
How do I make `docker buildx` display the spent time and not to omit

Comment: Does `docker buildx build --progress=plain` work, the same as [Why is docker build not showing any output from commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804749/why-is-docker-build-not-showing-any-output-from-commands)

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi! Not sure, but since the output is there, I don't think this command is the case. In fact, I figure out the reason, go check the response pls.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, that's a normal behaviour. Docker does not hide neither omit nothing.

Instead, `docker buildx` does stuff in parallel. Which means, different processes produce multiple outputs. These outputs compete on your screen. This looks funny sometimes, see:

```
//let's pretend some logs happened earlier

//npm ci at "deps" stage #1
#14 [deps 7/7] RUN npm ci
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 12.58MB / 165.14MB 0.6s
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 22.02MB / 165.14MB 0.9s
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 35.65MB / 165.14MB 1.4s
#14 ... //here it is broken to let other streams to display

//another stage! called "builder"
#13 [builder 2/6] WORKDIR /app
#13 extracting sha256:6fb1b25da51088e0fd1776f0b761b6d6b10d19b644e4c0d2a0e7c6d2237d8c65 1.2s done
#13 DONE 1.8s
//it's done immediately

//npm ci #2 - it's still going
#14 [deps 7/7] RUN npm ci
#14 ...
//interrupted again as other things have happened

//yet one more step from the "builder" stage that is done right away
#15 [builder 3/6] COPY . .
#15 DONE 0.8s

//npm ci #3 - yet one more excerpt from "deps" stage
#14 [deps 7/7] RUN npm ci
#14 extracting sha256:7c212e964304cc15fbcf39bdd14d4f36a521a643dd3e51e781813b312de7af4d 0.3s done
#14 extracting sha256:24586cb5165f566576965c06a65122a81074b5e9585cdc76bb77dbaeda2f405e 0.1s done
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 65.01MB / 165.14MB 2.9s
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 77.59MB / 165.14MB 3.3s
#14 sha256:cb63df9e77a82ef8a8e520cbc17c2d84edf9e2d13e48f7b2bb87cbffcb84d168 165.14MB / 165.14MB 6.6s done
#14 DONE 6.9s
//see, it's still completed! and the time is displayed properly. just not in one move, you have to scroll
```

Thank you all :)