# Dockerfile - Get output during docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Tried lots of searches for this and am drawing a blank.

I have a docker file that isn't building.  I'd like to do something like:
RUN echo $(ls *)
and see what exactly is in my current directory.  Cause I feel like something is missing as I'm getting weird errors when I run my dotnet restore command.  When I run said command locally the command works just fine.  And the same command works for other dockerfiles in other projects.

How can I see what the content of my docker image is while it is being build?

Edit:
Adding Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS build
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS build

ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ARG version

ENV USE_NET6_ARTIFACTS_CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER=false
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
    "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<CompanyNameHere>/_packaging/<CompanyNameHere>/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | bash
RUN echo "${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}"

WORKDIR /src

COPY NuGet.Config . 
COPY src/AppPortal.Web/*.csproj AppPortal.Web/

RUN dotnet restore AppPortal.Web/AppPortal.Web.csproj --configfile NuGet.Config

COPY src/ .

# Remove any appsettings (except appsettings.json) so they do not get bundled in the docker image
RUN  find . -type f -name appsettings.*.json -exec rm {} \;

WORKDIR /src/AppPortal.Web
RUN dotnet build "AppPortal.Web.csproj" -c Release --no-restore

FROM build AS publish

WORKDIR /src/AppPortal.Web

RUN dotnet publish "AppPortal.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app --no-build

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AppPortal.Web.dll"]
```

Error Message:

```
Removing intermediate container 9dfae1c6d08b
 ---> 48358f7e2161
Step 21/35 : RUN dotnet restore AppPortal.Web/AppPortal.Web.csproj --configfile NuGet.Config
 ---> Running in b4e6724f09d9
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore AppPortal.Web/AppPortal.Web.csproj --configfile NuGet.Config' returned a non-zero code: 145
```

Running the same dotnet restore command locally works just fine.

Comment: There is always the option to just start the base image and executes the command - one after another - as the dockerfile would (in reality, this is what docker does to create an image).

Comment: Please provide your dockerfile so we can help a bit more, getting `nonsensical errors` dose not mean anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Added the Dockerfile and the error.  Frustrated with this one as I have a dozen other inherited projects that work just fine.  But this particular one gives me an error that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Ok, in going cross eyed comparing with another working dockerfile I realized that I have aspnet:3.1 for the AS Build.  And what it actually should be is sdk:3.1

My question was originally intended to be more of a "How do I output the contents of a command like RUN echo $(ls *)" so that I can see the outputs of my folders.  I had another project that for some odd reason required me to add application/... in front of everything.  Even though it should be the same as all the others.

Comment: It looks like you're using the "classic" builder and not BuildKit, so you should see the output of all `RUN` commands, like what you show in the final output.  (Compare [Why is docker build not showing any output from commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804749/why-is-docker-build-not-showing-any-output-from-commands) if you were using BuildKit.)  Just `RUN ls`: both `echo $(command)` and `ls *` add unnecessary wrappers and expansions you don't need.

Comment: I'm using whatever latest docker is as of a month ago.  From that link you shared, the --progress=plain option worked for me.  Also thanks for helping me simplify my docker command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Maze helped me find the answer:

I needed to add --progress=plain / EXPORT BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain to my docker command / file.

Greatly appreciate the help!